# What is the purpose of the default keyword in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qt4, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to figure out what the default keyword in QML is.

In this example :http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-ui-components-tabwidget.html,
how is it being used?

Since in the example it says that

> any child items of the TabWidget are actually added to the 'stack'
>   item's children.

But in main.qml, Rectangles are added as children of TabWidget.

Can someone give me a clearly understanding of the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties) about it?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I did read it, but i was not able to understand how it is being used the in TabWidget example. Plus the documentation you sent is for import QtQuick 2.0, will it be the same for import QtQuick 1.0 or import QtQuick 1.1??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically the default property of the QML object. That is, when you do not specify it explicitly, it will fall back to that. See the more detailed explanation and example in the  the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties):

> Default Properties
>   An object definition can have a single default property. A default property is the property to which a value is assigned if an object is declared within another object's definition without declaring it as a value for a particular property.
>   Declaring a property with the optional default keyword marks it as the default property. For example, say there is a file MyLabel.qml with a default property someText:

```
// MyLabel.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Text {
    default property var someText

    text: "Hello, " + someText.text
}
```

The someText value could be assigned to in a MyLabel object definition, like this:

```
MyLabel {
    Text { text: "world!" }
}
```

This has exactly the same effect as the following:

```
MyLabel {
    someText: Text { text: "world!" }
}
```

Note that this should be more or less the same in Qt 4, too, as the concept.

Answer (score 0):

It used to describe QML object attributes, specifically [default property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties)

Comment: I would suggest not to use link-only answers as they become broken over time.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is *could* be nifty, but it's not something you'd likely need too often. It may also confuse other developers when they are first reading an implementation of your custom type.  (Some would argue that, in general at least, "explicit is better than implicit"...)

In addition to reading the accepted answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086017/3220983), note this quote from Qt docs to understand the "default" keyword better:

> ...child objects can be added to any Item-based type without
> explicitly adding them to the children property. This is because the
> **default property** of Item is its data property, and any **items added to
> this** list for an Item **are automatically added to its list of children**.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties

So, normally the "default" property of an Item (or anything derived from that) is effectively the "children" of the object.  But, you can define how this works for your own custom types, and point the "default" to something other than a list a children.  So, when nesting something inside your implementation of the custom type, you'll modify that other "default" property instead of adding a child object.